# GAS Intel Syntax won't assemble mov rdi, offset:symbol

Tags: assembly, gcc, gnu-assembler, intel-syntax

I'm new to x86 assembly and I'm following a practical work for the basics.
I have 2 equivalent sample codes: One in AT&T syntax and the other on Intel syntax.
When compiling theses with GCC, everything works fine for the AT&T syntax, but GCC gives me errors for the Intel version. Theses two files compiles nicely on my school computers, but won't on my personal one.

I must be missing some gcc configuration but I can't find anything on the net.

Here is the sample code:

```
    .intel_syntax noprefix
    .global main

    .text
main:
    mov     rdi, offset:message
    call    puts
    mov     rax, 0
    ret

message:
    .asciz "Hello, world!"
```

And the error messages:

```
$> gcc -o hello_intel hello_intel.S
hello_intel.S: Assembler messages:
hello_intel.S:6: Error: bad expression
hello_intel.S:6: Error: junk `message' after expression
```

Comment: Do you have the same exact version of GCC on both computers?

Comment: FWIW, the assembler that I use (also Intel) doesn't accept the colon after `offset`.

Comment: Indeed they are not, 10.3.0 at school and 9.3.0 on my computer. I will try to update mine

Comment: No change with version 10.3.0

Comment: Try just `mov rdi, offset message`.  I've never seen a colon in that place.

Comment: Ok, that worked. Now I can't understand why this colon is there in the samples and why it work like a charm on my school computers...

Comment: What exact source file were you able to assemble on your school computer that used `offset:symbol`?  What did `as --version` say on that machine?